# How do I install erlang OTP 25 on ubuntu?

Tags: erlang

I am trying to install erlang 25 (and elixir 1.13) on my ubuntu VM, but the default version installed by apt is erlang 24.
I've tried both :

```
sudo wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.d
sudo apt update
```

and

```
sudo wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_2.0_all.d
sudo apt update
```

but in both case, running `apt-cache policy esl-erlang` didn't show the desired version. I have recently installed erlang 25 on a identical vm, and I don't remember struggling at all, so I'm guessing there's a simple way of doing it that I just forgot ?

I hope you can help me, thank you !

Comment: As this program is not related to programming, this question is better suited for e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Use [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl) or [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang).

Answer (score 1):

From the Erlang [OTP repo](https://github.com/erlang/otp#binary-distributions), you should do:

```bash
apt-get install erlang
```

If you decide to compile from source:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/erlang/otp.git
cd otp
git checkout maint-25    # current latest stable version
./configure
make
make install
```

Alternatively, you can use [Kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl):

```bash
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kerl/kerl/master/kerl
chmod a+x kerl
```

and place `kerl` in your `PATH` so that you can invoke it from the terminal (remember to `source` your `.bashrc` or similar if you update your `PATH` variable there, or open a new terminal to reload the `PATH` env), i.e.,

```bash
export PATH=<path-to-kerl>:$PATH
```

Instructions on how to use it [here](https://github.com/kerl/kerl#usage).

Comment: `apt-get install erlang` installs OTP v24 as of now.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the usage of the [Erlang Version Manager](https://github.com/robisonsantos/evm), thanks to which you can compile and install *any* Erlang OTP version you need, regardless of what the default version is currently available for your Linux distro.

#### Installation of Erlang Version Manager:

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/robisonsantos/evm /tmp/evm/
 $ cd /tmp/evm/
 $ /tmp/evm/install
 $ echo 'source ~/.evm/scripts/evm' >> ~/.bashrc
 $ bash
```

#### Installation of the specific Erlang OTP version:

```
 $ evm install 25.1.1 -y
 $ evm default 25.1.1
```